# PHP String is passed as Array param

Tags: php

json payload:

```
{
    "asunto":"something;somethingelse",
    "respuesta":"Hola, esta es la respuesta que debería mandarse desde correo. "
}
```

```
 list("asunto" => $asunto, "respuesta" => $respuesta) = utils_getJsonPayload(['asunto', 'respuesta']);
        [$convId, $messageId]  =  explode(';', trim($asunto));
        echo gettype($respuesta) . PHP_EOL;
        if(replyWhatsappMessage($messageId, $respuesta, $convId) && ($WaDB->unlockAndPushBotMessage($respuesta, $convId)))
```

My problem comes when passing $respuesta variable.
its an string (apparently) and 3rd line gettype will print string too.

But i will then get this error:
`b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught TypeError: WhatsappDB: :unlockAndPushBotMessage(): Argument #1 ($message) must be of type string, array given, called in`

the unlockAndPushBotMessage function:

```
public function unlockAndPushBotMessage(string $message,  string $id){  
            $botMessage = "Bot: \t $message \n";
            $result = $this->lockAndPush(false, $botMessage, $id);

            return $result;
        }
```

I have tried deleting special character, but it havent work either. I would appreciate any help and an explanation on this would be great.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($respuesta);` to see what it actually contains? And are you 100% sure this is the code that throws the error and that it's not called somewhere else as well? We also have no clue what your `utils_getJsonPayload()` function actually does or returns.

Comment: i just found out the problem

Comment: there shouldnt matter what that function does, since the type is checked after it. In case you still curious : https://onlinephp.io/c/70f26

Comment: _"there shouldnt matter what that function does"_ - The reason I asked is that it happens quite often that people share debugging details from multiple requests/tests as if it was one. The best thing to do is to share all relevant code, which helps us narrow the issue down and get better clarity so we can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem

as we could see. in Line 4

```
if(replyWhatsappMessage($messageId, $respuesta, $convId) && ($WaDB->unlockAndPushBotMessage($respuesta, $convId)))
```

Before unlockAndPushBotMessage, i was calling replyWhatsappMessage first.

replyWhatsappMessage was getting $respuesta  as param too.  The difference here, was, this parameter was **passed by reference**

```
 function replyWhatsappMessage(string &$waId, string &$reply, string $conversationId){
        if((extract(getBusinessInfo($conversationId)[0]))){
            if(([$apiKey, $businessPhone] = getBotCredentials($businessName, $botName))){
                $reply = sendWhatsappMessage($apiKey, $businessPhone, $phoneNumber, [
                    
                    "type" => 'text',
                    "id" => $waId,
                    "text" => [
                        "beurk" => '2e',
                        "body" => $reply,
                    ]

                ]);
                if($reply) return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

As it was passed by reference. in this function Line 4. instead of assigning to a function scope variable, i was mutating the original variable referenced.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.